# Inserir dados na tabela Oracle "sem returning id into"?

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, laravel-5.2

Estou usando o Laravel 5.2 e quando tenho inserir dados ele quer retornar o ultimo, mas no momento quero inserir e saber se a operação foi com sucesso. Minha função no `controller` está assim:

```
public function cadastrar(),
{
        $codigo= Request::input('codigo');
        $codigo1 = Request::input('codigo1');

        $model= new ModelCriado();
        $model->CD_SEQUENCIA   = "SEQUENCIA.NEXTVAL";
        $model->CD_CODIGO      = $codigo;
        $model->CD_CODIGO1     = $codigo1;
        $model->save();
        return response()->json( array( "response" => 1 ) );
    }
```

mas ele está dando essa mensagem:

> Error Code : 904
>       Error Message : ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier
>       Position : 128
>       Statement : insert into model (CD_SEQUENCIA, CD_CODIGO, CD_CODIGO1) values (:p0, :p1, :p2) returning id into :p3
>       Bindings : [SEQ_MODEL.NEXTVAL,759,123,0]

minha tabela só tem 3 colunas

```
CD_SEQUENCIA, CD_CODIGO, CD_CODIGO1
```

Como resolvo isso?

> **EDIÇÃO 1**

```
class ModelCriado extends Model
{
    protected $table = "model_criado";
    public $timestamps = false; 
}
```

Comment: Poste o seu model?!

Comment: Já. Editei para mostrar a minha model

Comment: Desculpa mas essa tabela tem algum campo serial, auto ou você que passa os 3 valores.?

Comment: Eu chamo uma sequencia

Comment: então vamos entender, o campo `CD_SEQUENCIA` é a sua `Sequencia` ou seja o banco vai gerar esse valor?

Comment: Exatamente. Isso mesmo!

Comment: Eu fiz uma resposta, mas, não sei o comportamento correto para `ORACLE` e talvez tudo isso dependa de como o pacote esteja configurado, o importante que você informe esse pacote na pergunta também, para que possamos ver as possibilidades, eu sei que o Eloquent para SQLSERVER, MySQL e Posgres funciona perfeitamente agora ORACLE não tive nenhuma experiência.

Comment: Achei sua resposta modesta, rsrs, porque resolveu meu problema, mas que pudesse dar certo 100% tive que criar uma trigger no oracle que fizesse o autoincremento parecido com o mysql, aquele sem precisar chamar o campo. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Então, o pacote é assim, não é culpa minha kkkkk entendeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom pelo visto o seu banco o campo `CD_SEQUENCIA` é o campo que tem o seu valor gerado pelo banco de dado, então tente configurar o `Model`, informando a sua `$primaryKey`:

```
class ModelCriado extends Model
{
    protected $table = "model_criado";
    public $timestamps = false;    
    protected $primaryKey = 'CD_SEQUENCIA';
    protected $fillable = ['CD_CODIGO', 'CD_CODIGO1'];
}
```

e tente inserir com o código abaixo:

```
public function cadastrar()
{
    $codigo= Request::input('codigo');
    $codigo1 = Request::input('codigo1');

    $model= new ModelCriado();  
    $model->CD_CODIGO = $codigo;
    $model->CD_CODIGO1 = $codigo1;
    $model->save();
    return response()
          ->json( array( "response" => 1 ) );
}

public function cadastrar()
{
    $codigo= Request::input('codigo');
    $codigo1 = Request::input('codigo1');

    $model= new ModelCriado();  
    $model->CD_CODIGO = $codigo;
    $model->CD_CODIGO1 = $codigo1;
    $model->save();
    return response()
          ->json( array( "response" => 1 ) );
}
```

ou

```
public function cadastrar()
{
    $codigo= Request::input('codigo');
    $codigo1 = Request::input('codigo1');

    $model = ModelCriado::create(Request::all());   

    return response()
          ->json( array( "response" => 1 ) );
}
```

ou

```
public function cadastrar()
{
    $codigo= Request::input('codigo');
    $codigo1 = Request::input('codigo1');

    $model = new ModelCriado(Request::all());   
    $model->save();

    return response()
          ->json( array( "response" => 1 ) );
}
```

ou

```
public function cadastrar()
{
    $codigo= Request::input('codigo');
    $codigo1 = Request::input('codigo1');

    $model = new ModelCriado();
    $model->fill(Request::all());
    $model->save();

    return response()
          ->json( array( "response" => 1 ) );
}
```

Comment: O que significa a variável  $fillable?

Comment: @adventistaam eu não completei a resposta, mas, `$fillable` significa gravaçaõ em massa, e um jeito de fazer o cadastro vou editar e colocar na resposta

Comment: Apenas com o create é possivel salvar também?

Comment: tem outro jeito também que vê

Comment: Com certeza, é que são meus primeiros passos com laravel

Comment: Não conseguindo é recuperar esse ultimo registro, mas fica pra proxima pergunta rsrs. E pesquisas também

Comment: @adventistaam verifique se está depois do código save, tipo $model->save(); var_dump($save->toArray()); só para verificar se retornou.

Comment: Variavel `$save` mesmo?

Comment: Não desculpas `$model->toArray()` !!!